# Redgate Source Control commit changes throws trace filename exception

Tags: redgate

Whenever I try to commit changes to source control I get this error message. Trace file name '' is invalid. The statement has been terminated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling and re-enabling the default trace.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'default trace enabled', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'default trace enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```